# Conditional Merge based on variable in column of dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a dataframe that I would like to do a merge, but conditionally based on the variable in a column:

`df`

```
 code hours
  ot   1:00
 pto   8:00
```

`df2`

```
  code hours hours_convert
   pto  1:00     8
```

`df3`

```
 code hours hours_convert
   ot   1:00    9
```

`Ideal_dataframe`

```
 code hours hours_convert
   ot   1:00     9
  pto   1:00     8
```

I tried a pd.merge, but am having trouble with an if statement executing based on the dataframe column 'code'..

I also tried an np.where, which only was allowing me to place a specified string, but not do a merge

Ideal_dataframe = code hours hours_convert
                   ot   1:00     9
                  pto   1:00     8

1. List item

Comment: "but conditionally based on the variable in a column" please explain in more detail.

Comment: Can you convert your question to a general example with A, B, C, 1, 2, 3 so it is easier to read. Thanks.